# Save data from online text file to local variable

Tags: java, android

If I have a text file online containing a string. How can I pull the data from it and save it into a local String variable?

For example, say there is a file located at www.myserver.com/File.txt and it only contains one line: "12345"

How can I have my app read the file, and save the "12345" as a string variable that can be used within the app?

So here is how I managed to do this:

```
final AsyncTask < Object, Object, String > task = new AsyncTask < Object, Object, String > ()
{
    protected String doInBackground (Object. . .o)
    {
        try
        {
            URL site = new URL ("www.myserver.com/File.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner (site.openStream ());
            return s.nextLine ();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException ("Incorrect URL", e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException ("Can't fetch file content from url", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the file and type cast the content to integer and store it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
int i = 0;
if(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
     i = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need of download. just open and stream it and save in a file